# I have a Segfault, bad allocation?

Tags: c++, sfml

This is my code :

```
t_game_elements         *initializeEnvironnement(sf::RenderWindow *window)
{
    t_game_elements *gameElements;

    playerBat       playerBatOne(0, 200);
    playerBat       playerBatTwo(790, 200);

    gameElements = (t_game_elements *)malloc(1000);
    gameElements->playerOne = playerBatOne;
    gameElements->playerTwo = playerBatTwo;
    *gameElements->playerOne.getShape();
    window->draw(*playerBatOne.getShape()); // this line don't segfault
    window->draw(*gameElements->playerOne.getShape()); // this line segfault
    return (gameElements);
}

int                     main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow    window(sf::VideoMode(800, 500), "Pong", sf::Style::Default);
    t_game_elements     *elements;

    elements = initializeEnvironnement(&window);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed)
            {
                if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape)
                {
                    window.close();
                }
            }
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        // window.clear();
        // window.draw(*elements->playerOne.getShape());
        // window.draw(*elements.playerTwo->getShape());
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}

class           playerBat
{
    public:
        playerBat(int x, int y);
        sf::RectangleShape *getShape();
        void setShape(sf::RectangleShape *Shape);
        int test = 10;
    private:
        sf::RectangleShape shapeBat;
};

typedef struct  s_game_elements
{
    playerBat   playerOne;
    playerBat   playerTwo;
}               t_game_elements;

playerBat::playerBat(int x, int y)
{
    sf::RectangleShape rectangle(sf::Vector2f(120, 50));
    rectangle.setSize(sf::Vector2f(10, 100));
    rectangle.setPosition(x, y);
    rectangle.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
    shapeBat = rectangle;
}

void playerBat::setShape(sf::RectangleShape *Shape)
{
    shapeBat = *Shape;
}

sf::RectangleShape *playerBat::getShape()
{
    return &shapeBat;
}
```

I allocate 1000 bytes just to be sure I allocate enough memory, I will change it when I will fix the segfautlt first.

I tried to display the variable 'test' of my class and it works fine.

Have an idea why I segfault ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, the presence of manual dynamic allocation is bad.

Comment: @LogicStuff Why is it bad ? I only did C before and I am used to dynamic allocate everything.

Comment: Just don't do it if there's no need. If there is, we have `new`/`delete` in C++, smart pointers and `std::vector` if you're creating an array. Anyways, how did you come up with `1000` as the number of bytes to allocate?

Comment: I just chose it arbitrarily, habitualy I do `malloc(sizeof(name_of_struct))` . So I can allocate a structure with `new ` ?

Comment: `new` is part of the language, usually preferred to a library function.

Comment: `1000` is just a number of bytes, right? If you wanted to allocate one thousand objects, you have to multiply it by it its size... But I don't know if that was the problem, you have a number of pointers in your code. Note that SFML wants you to use references over pointers, `sf::RenderWindow *window` doesn't match with that.

Comment: This is C++ code. Why the C tag?

Comment: @Dimitri You have to show us more code. How are `playerBat`'s member functions defined?

Comment: @LogicStuff I edited my post.

Comment: I am afraid, this code is beyond salvation. Get rid of all the pointers first. You do not seem to need any of them on the first glance.

Comment: @SergeyA Yes you were right, I just get rid of them and all is working fine !